# Why is it that O(N + P) where P < N/2 reduces to O(N)?

Tags: asymptotics

My book says that

> If $P < N/2$ then we know that N is the dominant term so we an drop the $O(P )$."

If it was $O(N + P)$ where $P > N/2$ what would it reduce to?

Comment: Have you tried to go back to the definition and prove it yourself?

Comment: $P>N/2$ is equivalent to $N<2P$

Comment: Don't think about it as "reducing" Landau terms. Two terms can be equivalent; that's the claim here.

Comment: As long as $P = O(N)$, we have $O(N + P) = O(N + O(N)) = O(N) + O(O(N)) = O(N) + O(N) = O(N)$ (following formal manipulation rules as in _Concrete Mathematics_ say). In other words: if $P < cN$ for large enough $N$, then $N + P < (c+1)N$ for large enough $N$, so $N+P$ is $O(N)$.

Answer (score 3):

In the Big-O notation, constant factors are irrelevant.

Then if $N>P$, $O(N+P)$ reduces to $O(N)$, by swapping $N$ and $P$ we have that if $P>N$, $O(N+P)$ reduces to $O(P)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f = O(N+P)$
if $P<N/2$ ,  $f = O(P+N)$ implies $f = O(N+N/2)$  
$O(N+N/2) = O(N)$
 $f=O(N)$ 
if $P>N/2$ then same reduction for $f=O(P)$

Comment: Why do you use the $f$ here? It seems completely redundant. Also, what does this add the answer  already given?